# how to create and reference tagged counters

Tags: notebooks

For all its emphasis on the notebook interface, I struggle to find documentation supporting how to effectively write reports.  (Is author tools even maintained?  Will BibTeX support ever return?  Etc.)  Here is something trivial to do in LaTeX: tag a section counter (with `\label`) and later refer to it (with `\ref`), so that one can refer in the text to the section number in which material appears, and have that automatically updated if the document structure changes.  Main question: how would one do the equivalent in Mma?

I found a few potential clues in
http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/TechNotes/186/CounterTutorial.nb?file_id=2400 
but surely there is something better/more-advanced by now.  (And is `CounterBox` as completely undocumented as it seems to be?)